# Windows7 / WiFi Issue

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

My laptop with windows7 is in trouble.

It use to work as a charme but, unfortunately, my power supplier stops work. I bought one onto web and waited for it nearly two weeks. My laptop hasn't a working battery so it was turned off during this two weeks.

When I start it again date wasn't good (something like 1971) and I cannot connect with WiFi to my LAN and to any othe WiFi networks (I tried to connect to my Nexus hotspot).
So after a lot of tries, like uninstall wireless adapter, update drivers, release my ip address, reset router, and so on, I just formatted my laptop (I wanted to do in a while to be honest ...).

When I turned on again I was able to connect all WiFi network I tested but not the one I have at home (the original one of the question). Of course I can connect to my LAN with other devices.

How can I procede? Any advices?

## EDIT

[image: settings]

[image: Security Settings]

[image: wireless_ac]

[image: Advanced Wireless]

[image: wds]

[image: wps]

Comment: Information about which 802.11 standards your equipment supports is required to help out.

Comment: @Ramhound: how can I provide them? P.S.: Remember that before power supplier fails, all worked well

Comment: @Ramhound: I attached some pictures, hope you can retrieve info you need

Comment: I only need a couple word response indicating which frequency your access point is broadcasting at and what 802.11 modes it would accept ( 802.11ac, 802.11g, 802.11n, ect ) I don't need 6 pictures of every single configuration option of your router.

Comment: Since the system date went to **1971**, it seems the coin cell that powers the clock and BIOS memory is dead. That should be checked first and replaced if necessary, as some connection schemes require clocks to be synchronized; see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/clock-skew-too-great-while-getting-initial-credentials.html. You may need to remove the battery to force BIOS to reset cleanly, too.

Comment: Have you restarted your home router? Can your pc find this particular network SSID? What error msg do you get when you try to connect to it?

Comment: @Immanuel: yes, I can find that particular SSID and I can't simply connect, default message that you get when you can't connect (now I'm formatting and trying to install a CentOS to verify something)

Answer (score 1):

You could reboot your router, connect your laptop via LAN and http to the router to again see the configuration settings.  Might be useful to call your ISP tech support on the phone for them to help with the settings.  If you can't see it in your wireless networks, chances are SSID is not broadcasting...